# Adding a className to <div> onClick <a> in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built a modal in ReactJS which needs to be triggered by clicking an `<a>` to add `.active` class to the modal `<div className="newsletterModal">`.

Once class is active as `newsletterModal active` the `onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}` is successful in removing the `active` class but how can I add the `active` class from within my `footer`?

In Newsletter.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Link from 'gatsby-link';
class Newsletter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {addClass: false}
    }
    toggle() {
      this.setState({addClass: !this.state.addClass});
    }
    render() {
      let toggleModal = ["newsletterModal"];
      if(this.state.addClass) {
        toggleModal.push('active');
      }
      return(
            <div className={toggleModal.join(' ')}>
                <div className="newsletterContainer">
                   <span className="modalClose">
                       <a onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} href="javascript:;"><svg>...</svg></a>
                   </span>                       
                   <content /> 
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Newsletter
```

In Footer.js (where I want the link to add the class set within Newsletter.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
const Footer = (props) => (
    <footer>
        <a onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} href="javascript:;">
            Newsletter
        </a>        
    </footer>
)
export default Footer
```

index.js where both are called to the template - please note that I have a class being added to show the menu too from within this file. Perhaps it is possible to combine my `is-menu-visible` with `newsletterModal active`?

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import { Link, withPrefix } from 'gatsby-link'
import '../assets/scss/main.scss'
import Header from '../components/global/Header'
import Menu from '../components/global/Menu'
import Newsletter from '../components/global/Newsletter'
import Footer from '../components/global/Footer'
class Template extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isMenuVisible: false,
            loading: 'is-loading'
        }
        this.handleToggleMenu = this.handleToggleMenu.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({loading: ''});
        }, 100);
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        if (this.timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
        }
    }

    handleToggleMenu() {
        this.setState({
            isMenuVisible: !this.state.isMenuVisible
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props

        return (
            <main id="app" className={`body ${this.state.loading} ${this.state.isMenuVisible ? 'is-menu-visible' : ''}`}>
                <Helmet>
                    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
                </Helmet>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div className="sub-wrapper">
                        <Header onToggleMenu={this.handleToggleMenu} />
                        <div className="gutter">
                            {children()}
                            <Footer />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Menu/>
                <Newsletter />
            </main>
        )
    }
}

Template.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.func
}

export default Template
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by adding `showActive` state in `Template` class.

Add callback function in `Footer`:

```
const Footer = props => (
  <footer>
    <a onClick={props.onClick}>Newsletter</a>
  </footer>
);
```

Instead of `setState` inside, read `addClass` from `props`:

```
class Newsletter extends Component {
  render() {
    let toggleModal = ["newsletterModal"];
    if (this.props.addClass) {
      toggleModal.push("active");
    }
    return (
      <div className={toggleModal.join(" ")}>This part should update!</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Add an event handler for footer `onClick` event:

```
const Header = props => (
  <header onClick={props.onToggleMenu}>
    <h1>Main Page Title</h1>
  </header>
)

class Template extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showActive: false
    };
  }

  toggleClass = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showActive: !prevState.showActive
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Header onToggleMenu={this.toggleClass} />
        <Newsletter addClass={this.state.showActive} />
        <Footer onClick={this.toggleClass} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:**
If you have multiple components interact with each other, it's better to consider using a state manager, such as **Redux** or **MobX**

**Update:**
I updated my code, so it can run standalone as a complete demo.
There is the [codesandbox demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/r798zr8ky4)

Comment: Cheers. It does work nicely thank you. I think I shall take your suggestion and look to Redux though.

Comment: @Darren You're welcome. `MobX` requires minimal changes on your code structure, if you have a working project already. `Redux` has better support, and more suitable for a bigger project from the start.

Comment: Thank you. I think i'll need some time researching.

Comment: In the interim - my `<span className="modalClose"><a onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} href="javascript:;"><svg>...</svg></a></span> ` is now not working. What is the best way to do this? Cheers

Comment: @Darren What behavior do you expect? How about add a callback function to props, and then call footerTriggeredHandler just like footer to trigger the toggle?

Comment: The `<span className="modalClose">` is initially meant to add/remove the class. I have tried using the same triggers that are within the footer but they producing an error.

Comment: I have decided to take the same approach that I have with the menu trigger as seen in my index.js with `isMenuVisible`, using `isModalVisible` in the `id="app"`. The modal is being called from multiple components and it was going to get messy, adding these everywhere.

Comment: @Darren No worries. I attached a completely demo https://codesandbox.io/s/r798zr8ky4 Does this similar to what your want? I don't know what's inside your `Header`, so I just made something up. The key takeaway is: you want to keep most of states in one place, and then use props to update each child component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167309/discussion-between-darren-and-fisnan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `toggle()` method to your `<Footer />` component

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Link from 'gatsby-link';
import Footer from './Footer';

class Newsletter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {addClass: false}
    }
    toggle() {
      this.setState({addClass: !this.state.addClass});
    }
    render() {
      let toggleModal = ["newsletterModal"];
      if(this.state.addClass) {
        toggleModal.push('active');
      }
      return(
            <div className={toggleModal.join(' ')}>
                <div className="newsletterContainer">
                   <Footer onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} />                     
                   <content /> 
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Newsletter;
```

In your Footer.js file use the onClick function passed in as prop

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
const Footer = (props) => (
    <footer>
        <a onClick={this.props.onClick} href="javascript:;">
            Newsletter
        </a>        
    </footer>
)
export default Footer
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to explain better as I do not want the `<footer />` to be brought into the modal. Just a trigger within the `<footer />` to add the `.active` class to `newsletterModal`

Comment: Then you should store the state of `addClass` in the parent component that renders the newsletter modal and the footer and pass that down to newsletter modal

Comment: Thank you @yanhua. I have updated my question to further explain. I have previously tried your suggestion of within the parent, yet it failed because of another trigger being added to open the menu. Is their a way to combine the two?